# SOTI MobiControl Kiosk Mode

Tags: android, kiosk-mode, soti, mobicontrol

We are trying to use the Kiosk mode feature of SOTI MobiControl to run our application on a kiosk. We are currently testing on a Zebra TC52 (an Android device) until we get our Elo kiosks.

We’ve set up a profile for our app that uses the Lockdown configuration. It “kind of” works, but isn’t quite doing what we expect.

[image]

When we power on the machine, it comes up in the normal startup screen. If I swipe up, then it takes us to our app screen. However, the status bar is showing, and can be pulled down.

[image]

[image]

However, if I click on the Home button, then the status bar goes away, and we’re closer to where we wanted to be. There is still a back button at the bottom of the screen.

[image]

We were hoping:

1. That when the machine starts, it would immediately go to our app screen, instead of requiring someone to swipe up to get the app to start.
2. That there would be no status bar, or bottom icons.
3. This app will be customer facing, so we want our app, and only our app, to ever show on the screen.

I’m not sure if any of these limitations are specifically because we’re using a TC52 instead of an actual kiosk device, but to my mind, they’re both just Android devices.

I have included screen shots of our configuration and the results on the device.

Can anyone see anything we are missing? Or are we expecting too much from the SOTI configuration for kiosks?

Answer (score 0):

at least to disable the Lock Screen you can use the free Zebra StageNow tool (https://www.zebra.com/de/de/support-downloads/software/utilities/stagenow.html).
You can create a lot of device specific setting, just check https://techdocs.zebra.com/mx/ for the setting to disable the swipe lock screen.

in StageNow you can, after finish the Profile, export the Config for MDM
(upper right corner)
In Soti Mobicontrol u can use a script within Packages, Filesync, or direct on Device

```
mxconfig /sdcard/yoursetting.xm
```

to import the Setting to the Devices.

Depending on your Soti MC Version there are also some Settings available in the Lockdown Setting Profile to disable the Notification Bar, maybe also u can find some other usefull Settings in the MX Matrix..

Oliver